# Are all even regular undirected Cayley graphs of Class 1?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, cayley-graphs

Are even order Cayley graphs of Class 1, that is, can they be edge-colored with exactly $m$ colors, where $m$ is the degree of each vertex?

I think yes, because of the symmetry the Cayley graphs possess unlike Petersen graph or Snarks. I also know of a few results in this direction in an old paper by Richard Stong. Any new conclusive result in this direction? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: I think you mean "exactly $m$ colours".

Comment: @ChrisGodsil yes, thanks, edited now

Comment: I think this might be open, even for $3$-valent Cayley graphs. See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895604000188 for example. (This is more general in a way, because it deals with vertex-transitive graphs, but more restrictive, because the group is soluble.)

Comment: Other than the Petersen graph and its truncation, are there actually any known vertex-transitive graphs that are not Class 1?

Comment: @GordonRoyle Can we use the fact that the automorphism group of the graph acts regularly on the vertices in partitioning the vertices into unique pairs, such that all the edges(pair of vertices) are covered in $m$ disjoint classes, thereby proving the graphs are class 1?

Comment: @vidyarthi If there were more non-Cayley vertex-transitive graphs of Class 2, then you might suspect that "regular subgroup" was important. But if the only exceptions are Petersen-related, then you might suspect that "not Petersen" is the crucial property. And any problem that has "not Petersen" as the key ingredient is one that I personally would avoid at all costs. Of course, it is a hard property to test computationally because chromatic index gets difficult quickly, and there aren't many non-Cayley graphs with few edges to provide examples.

Comment: @GordonRoyle how about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019191/is-every-even-regular-and-even-order-of-a-graph-class-1/2019256#2019256) example? I think the graph given is not Petersen like? or is it? But, it is not vertex transitive, I suppose?

Comment: Disconnected doesn’t count because that is really just an odd order graph twice over. The second one is not transitive and in that case there are many examples.

Comment: @vidyarthi It's hard to answer a question of the form "Can we use the fact...". Can you use it? To help you see the difficulty, suppose we have a cubic Cayley graph with generating set an involution, and an element of odd order. This induces a natural partition of the edges into a perfect matching and a bunch of odd cycles. How would you use this to 3-colour the edges? Clearly, any 3-edge-colouring will NOT respect the natural edge-colouring, which makes it non-obvious why it should be useful at all.

Comment: @verret I think the method would work if the degree is even, that is without an involution in the generating set. Would it?

Comment: How would you deal with the case of degree $4$, say, where the generating set consists of two elements of odd order, and their inverses? (Or one element of odd order, one element of even order.)

Comment: @verret I have only tried very small transitive graphs from the usual source and finding the chromatic number of their line graphs, which is slow. It would make sense to exploit the particular nature of this problem to quickly find Class 1 graphs, but that will have to go on to the to-do list.

Comment: @GordonRoyle instead of finding the chromatic number for line graphs, why not try to partition the edge sets into disjoint ones(matchings), which I think is easier( although not algorithmically, but conceptually)

Comment: @verret yes, perfectly see your argument. But, I think we can form a partitioning of edges using the generating element and its right multiplication with group elements, if there is a single element which could generate the whole group, that is cyclic group, which is anyways proved. Since Cayley graph of Abelian group is cartesian product of circulant graphs, so similarly, it stands good for them too And, also, for the generating set consisting of only even order elements, contd...

Comment: I think the canonical edge matching would give us the desired coloring. So, for example the cayley graphs of dihedral groups of the form $D_{4n}$ would also be class $1$ colored by the canonical coloring. By the way, is there any relation between the graphs of two subgroups and their semi-direct products? Is it somewhat related to corona of the subgraphs?

Comment: @vidyarthi Abelian groups and dihedral groups and so on are very special groups, and very far from the general case. The answer to your original question is that this is still open, and probably quite hard. If you think you know how to do it, you should write it up, I'm sure some people would be interested. I think that's all I have to say about this.

Comment: @verret Will answering the question for  graphs of simple groups help in answering the full question? In that case, we have the alternating group, groups of lie type and the sporadic groups remaining. The direct products of simple groups could be treated using Cartesian products, but what about other extensions

Comment: @vidyarthi You tell us! I already said I think this question is hard, you're the one who think you know an approach. I would guess even the case of alternating groups (say) is quite hard. Note also that I don't agree with your comment about direct product of simple groups. A Cayley graph on such a group is not necessarily a Cartesian product.

Comment: @verret why is not the cayley graph of a direct product of groups a cartesian graph product of the individual graphs? I refer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064867/cayley-graphs-of-product-groups-is-product-of-cayley-graphs?), for example. Do you have any counterexamples?

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes, take any group which is a direct product, and then consider the complete graph on this group. This is not a (nontrivial) Cartesian product. To make it more explicit, consider for example the complete graph on 4 vertices, viewed as a Cayley graph on the Klein group. You only get a Cartesian product in a natural way if, for the generating set of the direct product, you take a union on generating sets of the direct factors.

Comment: @verret but the trivial generating set shown in my link would preserve the coloring properties, isnt it?

Comment: 1.This is not precise enough for me to answer: I don't know what you mean by "would preserve the coloring properties". 2.Even if this were the case, so what? For the problem at hand, you have to deal with arbitrary connection sets. I think you are still a bit confused about some very basic notions in the area. For example, judging by the question you linked to, it seems you're still a bit fuzzy on what is a Cayley graph. I think you should try to clear these things up before you move on to more complicated questions. Just my two cents. (Again) I think that's all I have to say about this.